# Mongoose: how to retrieve the name of every kitten in the collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following code based on the quickstart from Mongoose Docs.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
    var kittySchema = mongoose.Schema({
        name: String
    });

var kitten = mongoose.model('kitten', kittySchema);

kitten.find(function(err, kittens) {

    if(err) 
      return console.error(err);

    console.log(kittens[0].name);
});


});
```

What I want to do is log the name from each kitten in the DB.
The example above returns the name of the first kitten in the array with `kittens[0].name` but when I try to do the following:

```
for(var i in kittens){
  console.log(kittens[i].name);
}
```

it returns `undefined` for each item in the DB.

I have tried converting the `i` variable to a number because it comes as a string but no luck.

How can I retrieve the property name of every item that comes with `.find()`?

Comment: just do a regular `for` loop: `for (var i = 0; i < kittens.length; i++) {console.log(kittens[i].name);}`

Comment: Try adding: console.log(kittens); and see what the output is.  

It could be possible that you have kittens that do not have names!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you try this:

```
for(var i=0; i<kittens.length; i++){
  console.log(kittens[i].name);
}
```

since, `find` returns an array i.e. `kittens` here, `kittens.length` will give the `length` of the `kittens` array.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. This did the trick. I'm a little confused because I tried this before I posted a question and still got the undefined. I don't know what changed, or maybe I was just writing it in a wrong way. Anyways thank you for your answer!